# Gravity simulation doesn't work (Cloth Simulation)

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

my object isn't falling down in the cloth simulation I run. I didn't found any solution on the internet. I'm sure it's a simple one tho...
[image: Object not falling]
[image: Gravity settings]
Thanks in advance,
Tobi

Comment: Please share the blend file to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cloth simulation has pinned vertices, the object won't fall.

You would need to add a Rigid body constraint, and make the cloth simulation be the second constraint on the stack.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new to Blender, so I don't know if this will help, but you can also try checking the Gravity in the Scene Properties tab.  According to the Blender documentation, the default setting should be -9.810 to simulate Earth's gravity.

Good Luck!

Source:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/forces/gravity.html